# Box of text contains hidden message

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

I invented a novel encryption technique that hides a message in the below text box.

```
yrcjprieadbbsrmtaiuooilyzbeioaouwdmriuoueblqjrd
dnknnuzwycgsdpcrijmpkejvqkelgtpixlwwegsgjintrdq
stvfudxwxywqnkgquvtmmuwpqcasrqqacsrtidgbhxavwgm
blyamkfpueeivdmzibglducsltugmrxivpdregxfhztegws
cnwvakhtffxomxlvijxgmofnzhuxpnbexjrcegcwbyernvs
cbgkhowklhdeqnqwigtlmuvmkpaykgmecnzrulzlcuhhfmn
jdbwqyaaeeuihhpzuueiaugbmhuuuauudvsraeauitvyktj
```

> Hint about the message (in order to be less broad): After the necessary
>  decryption the message on your monitor can be seen from 10 metres.

Comment: I don't think this is [tag:lateral-thinking]. But it's definitely a [tag:cryptograms]

Comment: @Reticality indeed I am not sure if it really is lateral thinking, in your opinion should I delete that tag?

Comment: @ca If the task is just string manipulation, then the tag does not seem to fit.

Comment: Are you sure it's encryption and not just obfuscation?

Comment: @IanMacDonald If by obfuscation you mean adding random chars to an already decided message, no it is not that.

Comment: I feel like this is too broad. You should tell us more about the message and/or the encryption technique. You don't have to (and shouldn't) spell it out for us, but as it is there's no way for someone to know for sure that they got it right.

Comment: @RobWatts I think now it much clearer what to do, it is less broad isn't it?

Comment: @Caridorc That is indeed an intriguing hint!

Comment: @RobWatts should I put the hint inside a spoiler tag?

Comment: Probably wouldn't be a bad idea

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is:

> GOOD

This is obtained by:

> Converting all the non-vowels into dots, and looking at the resulting block of text.

Which gives:

> `......iea.......aiuooi....eioaou....iuoue.......
>  .....u..........i....e....e....i....e....i......
>  ....u...........u....u....a....a....i.....a.....
>  ...a....ueei....i....u....u....i....e......e....
>  ....a......o....i....o....u....e....e.....e.....
>  .....o.....e....i....u....a....e....u....u......
>  ......aaeeui....uueiau....uuuauu....aeaui.......`

Answer (score 13):

> The vowels encode the message as a picture.  Here they are all blacked out:
> `yrcjpr███dbbsrmt██████lyzb██████wdmr█████blqjrd
> dnknn█zwycgsdpcr█jmpk█jvqk█lgtp█xlww█gsgj█ntrdq
> stvf█dxwxywqnkgq█vtmm█wpqc█srqq█csrt█dgbhx█vwgm
> bly█mkfp████vdmz█bgld█cslt█gmrx█vpdr█gxfhzt█gws
> cnwv█khtffx█mxlv█jxgm█fnzh█xpnb█xjrc█gcwby█rnvs
> cbgkh█wklhd█qnqw█gtlm█vmkp█ykgm█cnzr█lzlc█hhfmn
> jdbwqy██████hhpz██████gbmh██████dvsr█████tvyktj`

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't get the preformat text to work inside a spoiler, which ruins the puzzle for everyone else from 10 meters away...

Comment: Fixed the formatting. The trick is to use <code> tags and <br> instead of newlines. It's weird, I know.

Comment: You should use the `<pre>` tag if it's not code.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Unfortunately `<pre>` tags do not render properly in spoiler blocks